# Can one declare block-level variables in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am new to Ruby and trying to understand Ruby Blocks.

Is there a way to include `i` in the following block or does it have to be declared outside the block like I did below?

```
  i = 0
  nums.each_with_index do |num, j|
    if num != 0
      nums[i], nums[j] = num, nums[i]
      i += 1
    end
  end
```

I tried initializing `i` as a block variable but it didn't work.

```
  nums.each_with_index do |num, j; i = 0|
```

Comment: Your question is a little awkward because what you are asking and what you want to achieve are opposite one another. *"Can one declare block-level variables in Ruby?"* Yes. You have shown that. In your second example `i` is scoped to the block and each time the block runs `i==0`, same as if you declared `i` inside the block. That being said you clearly are looking for a variable that is scoped outside of the block which you have shown in your initial example.

Comment: "it didn't work" is not a precise enough problem description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: [Block local arguments](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Block+Local+Arguments) do something else: they allow an existing outer variable to be explicitly [shadowed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) so that a) the outside value doesn't leak inside and b) assignments to the variable within the block are isolated and don't affect the outer variable. In your case, you do need to declare `i` outside of the block (as you did) or find a different approach that doesn't need such variable in the first place.

Comment: Don't be too hard on OP, this question is really hard to ask if you don't know what you actually need is a "local" value that is carried between each block invocation, and not "global" variable declared before the block, that stays accessible after the `each_with_index` call. In other words, just because you don't understand the question doesn't necessarily mean it's low-quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a trick to have `i` local to the block, and not "leak" outside of the iteration:

```rb
result  = [6, 7, 8].each_with_index.inject(42) do |i, (item, index)|
  i + item + index
end
puts result
# 66
```

This contrived example defines your `i` (starting from `42` just for example purposes, but you'd probably prefer `0`). And iterates over an array of items with their indexes, and sums it up.

`each_with_index` will return an Enumerator, on which you can call `inject` (which is also known as `reduce`) which takes an initial value and a block, and passes what is called `accumulator` value (basically `i` in your case, a variable you can use to accumulate results) as a first argument of this block, which you can use to `reduce` a collection of items to a single value.

I don't think there's any other way to do it. Variables defined inside of a block are visible only to that *invocation* of a block (so for each iteration, the whole block is executed so if you do `i = 0` it will be `0` for each item.

I believe what I suggested with `inject` would be an idiomatic solution if you don't want to declare a variable outside of the block.

So, your example would look something like this (please note that I could not test it, because your example is incomplete, i.e. you don't specify what `nums` is)

```rb
  nums.each_with_index.inject(0) do |i, (num, j)|
    if num != 0
      nums[i], nums[j] = num, nums[i]
      i + 1 # you can think of the last line in the block as `return` 
      # and the value becomes `i` in the next iteration, or is 
      # returned as a result of calling `inject` method if it was the 
      # last iteration
    end
    i # This will be what block returns, and current `i` value will be carried over to the next block iteration (or returned if it was the last one)  
  end
```

Comment: Might want to note that `i` is the return value from the block. This answer would be a lot more clear if it was tailored to the question asked via the code posted.

Comment: No problem; however your update is going to have an issue if `num` is ever 0 (which I assume is possible otherwise the check if pointless). When `num == 0` then `i` will then be `nil` and the next iteration will result in an  `TypeError`

Comment: Thanks! Just one minor comment: We need to return `i` after the if-statement in case `num` is not 0.

Comment: `[6, 7, 8].each_with_index.with_object([42]) { |(item, index), a| a[0] += item + index }.first #=> 66` also works, though I wouldn't advocate either solution.

Comment: @CarySwoveland why would you not advocate Greg's solution?

Comment: Mooch, simply because his code is more difficult to follow than yours. For example, when `inject` is used one generally expects the return value to be of interest, but that's not the case here. To protect `i` it is easiest to create a new scope by simply putting your code in a method, as I advocated in my answer. Incidentally, I upvoted Greg's answer because he showed a way to hide `i`, which is what you asked. You effectively asked whether it was possible, not if it should be done. I find questions asking if something is possible often have high educational value.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I see. So even though Greg's code looks more elegant and idiomatic to the uninitiated, my code is better by being more readable. 
I agree with you. `inject` does look out of place there, even to me. What are we even injecting?

Comment: "one generally expects the return value to be of interest, but that's not the case here" I don't think it's a valid point. `#each` also returns a value, but I rarely see it assigned at all. @Mooch feel free to use any of the working suggestions. The one with method is ok, the one with an extra `each` is confusing and would rather not pass a code review. I think it's worth getting yourself familiar with the `inject` approach, but it may be too soon if you're learning basics - make a note and come back to it when you're up for a challenge. Good luck on your Ruby journey!

Answer (score 1):

You want to keep the value of `i` away from prying eyes after `nums` is modified.

An easy (but absurd) solution is to enclose the code in a block that is executed once.

```
nums = [1, 2, 0, 3]
```

```
["hey, diddle, diddle,"].each do
  i = 0
  nums.each_with_index do |num,j|
    if num != 0
      nums[i], nums[j] = num, nums[i]
      i += 1
    end
  end
end
  #=> 3
```

```
nums
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 0]
i #=> NameError: undefined local variable or method `i' for main:Object
```

---

Rather than resorting to contortions to hide the value of `i` you should simply enclose your code in a method.

```
def doit(nums)
  i = 0
  nums.each_with_index do |num,j|
    if num != 0
      nums[i], nums[j] = num, nums[i]
      i += 1
    end
  end
end
```

```
doit [1, 2, 0, 3]
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 0]
nums
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 0]
```

Comment: This would work, but it's terrible advice. Having an `each` only to be able to have a block whose only purpose is to define an "ephemeral" variable is so unorthodox it will confuse most people working on that code.

Comment: @Greg, the OP asked, "Is there a way to include `i` in the following block...?", not whether it is a good idea to do so. There are plenty of questions on SO asking whether something is possible, even when one would be crazy to do it. I chose my example to illustrate why it would not be good programming practice, that I am not providing "advice".

Comment: Good point! Not only "best practices" idea constitute an answer, but I also believe we need to be clear (especially when newbies are concerned) where something is possible and not recommended. Thanks for the update.